# One To Many populate model containing Primery Key other then ID in waterline mysql

Tags: node.js, waterline

I Have two models in **Waterline ORM** with **Node js** whose declaration is as follow:

Student.js:

```
module.exports = {
identity: 'student',
connection:'someMysqlServer',
schema:true,
migrate: 'safe',
  attributes: {
f_id: {
 primaryKey: true,
 unique: true,
 autoIncrement: true
},
result:{
collection:'marks',
via:'student'
 }
};
```

Marks.js:

```
    module.exports = {
    identity: 'marks',
    connection:'someMysqlServer',
 schema:true,
    migrate: 'safe',
  attributes: {
     student:{
       model:"student",
       columnName:"student"
}
```

Now,the query to populate studentin marks is working well but vise versa isn't working.

```
  db('marks').find({id:id}).populate('student').exec(function(e,r){});
```

this isn't working while i can see foreign key of student in marks table too.

Is it a problem that only the primry key with name "id" is supported and populated??????